# how to get an np array of shape (32,224,224) where [0] contains (244,224) 1's and [1] only 2's?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

So I need an array of the shape (32,224,224) where [0] contains only 1's [1] only contains 2's etc. The only one I can think of is to make an array 1:32 and stack that 32 times. How can I do this more efficiently? (I am using python 3)

Comment: There are [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) or [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) that can help you.

Comment: is readonly ok?  Or do you actually want to allocate that much memory?

Comment: Actually, *why* do you want this array?  It seems like you may have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) with broadcasting

Comment: hmm I might, I have this array of shape (32,224,224) and I have an array of 32 weights. I want each of the 32 (224,224) arrays to be multiplied with the weight in that weight array sor array[0] must be multiplied with weight[0]. When you try to do this by just * the dimensions are not correct so I thought lets make a (32,224,224) and multiply elementwise. So precisely what Ken gives as a solution

Comment: What you actually want then is `weights[:, None, None] * arr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a big, memory-hungry array to multiply, broadcast the multiplication:

```
weights = np.arange(1,33)
arr = np.random.rand(32, 224, 224)
```

Instead of this (using @ken's solution):

```
warr1 = (np.ones([32,264,264]).T * weights).T * arr
```

Do this:

```
warr2 = weights[:, None, None] * arr

np.allclose(warr1, warr2)
Out: True
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant, but see if this gets you the output you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

myarray = (np.ones([32,264,264]).T * np.arange(1,33)).T
```

Output:

```
print(myarray)

[[[  1.   1.   1. ...,   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1. ...,   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1. ...,   1.   1.   1.]
  ..., 
  [  1.   1.   1. ...,   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1. ...,   1.   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1. ...,   1.   1.   1.]]

 [[  2.   2.   2. ...,   2.   2.   2.]
  [  2.   2.   2. ...,   2.   2.   2.]
  [  2.   2.   2. ...,   2.   2.   2.]
  ..., 
  [  2.   2.   2. ...,   2.   2.   2.]
  [  2.   2.   2. ...,   2.   2.   2.]
  [  2.   2.   2. ...,   2.   2.   2.]]

 [[  3.   3.   3. ...,   3.   3.   3.]
  [  3.   3.   3. ...,   3.   3.   3.]
  [  3.   3.   3. ...,   3.   3.   3.]
  ..., 
  [  3.   3.   3. ...,   3.   3.   3.]
  [  3.   3.   3. ...,   3.   3.   3.]
  [  3.   3.   3. ...,   3.   3.   3.]]

 ..., 
 [[ 30.  30.  30. ...,  30.  30.  30.]
  [ 30.  30.  30. ...,  30.  30.  30.]
  [ 30.  30.  30. ...,  30.  30.  30.]
  ..., 
  [ 30.  30.  30. ...,  30.  30.  30.]
  [ 30.  30.  30. ...,  30.  30.  30.]
  [ 30.  30.  30. ...,  30.  30.  30.]]

 [[ 31.  31.  31. ...,  31.  31.  31.]
  [ 31.  31.  31. ...,  31.  31.  31.]
  [ 31.  31.  31. ...,  31.  31.  31.]
  ..., 
  [ 31.  31.  31. ...,  31.  31.  31.]
  [ 31.  31.  31. ...,  31.  31.  31.]
  [ 31.  31.  31. ...,  31.  31.  31.]]

 [[ 32.  32.  32. ...,  32.  32.  32.]
  [ 32.  32.  32. ...,  32.  32.  32.]
  [ 32.  32.  32. ...,  32.  32.  32.]
  ..., 
  [ 32.  32.  32. ...,  32.  32.  32.]
  [ 32.  32.  32. ...,  32.  32.  32.]
  [ 32.  32.  32. ...,  32.  32.  32.]]]


print(myarray.shape):

(32, 264, 264)
```

Comment: Just a minor thing. It's not a perfect `cube` since the length of axis 0 is not `224`; so I'm not sure whether you can call it as `cube`. By definition, the length has to be the same on all 3 dimensions to call it as a `cube`

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the array?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((32,224,224))
for i in range(32):
   a[i,:,:] = i+1
```

Comment: Yes but I thought that there would be a more efficient solution as I need to do this a lot of times